# How to manipulate a shell script output and display it on a webpage using PHP

Tags: php, shell

The output of my shell script look like this

```
RUN    TRT FLO MAT TOPWT HARWT  RAIN  TIRR   CET  PESW  TNUP  TNLF   TSON TSOC
           dap dap kg/ha kg/ha    mm    mm    mm    mm kg/ha kg/ha  kg/ha t/ha
  1 WH   1 217 250  7615  2848   600     0   422   141    76    54   7841   79
  2 WH   2 217 250 10018  4150   600     0   431   139   105    78   7841   79
  3 WH   3 217 250 11087  4416   600     0   430   138   131   163   7841   79
  4 WH   4 217 250  5895  1737   600   213   446   144    52    16   7838   79
  5 WH   5 217 250  7787  2338   600   213   446   143    69    18   7838   79
  6 WH   6 217 250  9610  3519   600   213   450   139    94    46   7838   79
```

I am trying to load these contents into a table on a webpage.

NOTE: I used `explode()` but couldnt figure out a way to get the values from the array into a table.
"Correct me if my approach is wrong".

My code:

```
<?php
$output =  shell_exec("cd DSSAT46; ./dscsm046 CSCER046 A KSAS8101.WHX  2>&1");

$arr = explode(" ",$output);
print_r($arr);
echo "<table><tr>";
  foreach ($output as $row) 
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['RUN'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['TRT'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['FLO dap'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat, making this question very broad.There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i have updated my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `explode()` you need to do it in two steps. In my answer I am assuming:

1. The first two rows of your output contains title of your data hence wont change.
2. You have `\n` as line separator and `\t` (tab) as column separator.

You can try the following code:

```
<?php
// assuming $output contains the output you got from shell
$lines = explode("\n", $output);
// starting from 2 to ignore the title
echo '<table>';
for ($i = 2; $i < sizeof($lines); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $columns = explode("\t", $lines[$i]);
    foreach ($columns as $data) {
        echo '<td>'.$data.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: That worked but the column names  of the table doesnt align with column values. Any fix for that?

Comment: Is this the `RUN    TRT FLO MAT ...` you are talking about? in my answer I assumed that part wont change and therefore you can hardcode it matching the column, for example, add something like, `echo '<th><td>RUN</td></th>....'`  right after `echo '<table>'`

Comment: i hard coded it but the output is algined to the left and the column names like `RUN TRT FLO MAT` are alined to the right..